# Laravel - How can I handle variable queue names

Tags: php, laravel, queue

I'd like to know if it's possible to handle variable queues names in Laravel 5.5.

For example :

```
ProcessJob::dispatch()->onQueue("queue-name-" . $var);
```

When I launch the worker the classic way, only default queue is treated. How could I make the worker treat all Jobs without specify queues names ('cause I don't know its names) ?

Thank you

Comment: you need to have your worker running before you disptch the job..

Comment: you can specify the queue name (even more then one) but you have to know their names first `php artisan queue:work --queue=name1,name2,name3 `

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
Yeah, I wanted to know if it's possible to do it without knowing queues names..

Comment: Are your queue names predictable or completely random? If they are predictable, what's the naming scheme? Additionally could you explain a bit more, how you want to spread the jobs over the queues?